# How is publishing in PLoS One perceived by peers and hiring committees?

Tags: publications, journals, plos-one

I am a final year doctoral candidate and have three other publications in decent field-specific journals. Will an addition of a first authored plos one article make my cv or publication record thus far look worse, especially to peers and hiring committees (for academic/non-academic jobs)?

Comment: Welcome to academia.se! As it stands, this question seems hard to answer, since it is both very specific (most of the people on this site aren't familiar with PLoS One) and lacks detail (e.g. what country and field you are in). You are likely to get better answers by describing what makes PLoS One special and then asking a broader question about how this type of publication is viewed.

Comment: Plose one is not a good journal. They refuse a good paper as they do not understand the topic. Also, they accept very low quality papers. (Based on experience as an editor).